# Time difference calculation is incorrect

Tags: python

I am calculating time difference between `then` and `now`. The result is `8 days`, but I expect it to be 7. Probably it's happening because I populate `then` with a date from CSV file and its time is `00:00:00`,  `datetime.now()` return date with time `15:22:20.726944`. Is there a way to solve the problem? Time doesn't really matter for me, can I make it `00:00:00` as well?

```
then = max(df.Date) 
# 2021-08-02 00:00:00 

now = datetime.now() 
# 2021-08-09 15:22:20.726944

print(max(df.Date) - datetime.now())
# -8 days +08:36:30.249498
```

Comment: It's -8 days + XX h, which is between 7 days & 8 days ?

Comment: can you try `print(datetime.now() - max(df.Date))`

Comment: Reverse your arguments: `print(datetime.now() - max(df.Date))`

Comment: The result of your subtraction is `datetime.timedelta(days=-8, seconds=31059, microseconds=273056)`. That is, *minus* 8 days, *plus* 31059 seconds, which is less than 8 days. By ignoring the time component you are rounding up, because of the difference in sign. Reverse the subtraction and you will get 7 days, 55340 seconds, as you seem to expect.

Comment: If, instead, you are wondering why the delta isn't something like -7 days, -55340 seconds, time delta values are normalized so that the seconds and microseconds are *always* positive, and the sign of the interval is determined by the days alone. This ensures that an interval of size `t` is unique, for every `x`/`y` pair such that `x - y == t`. For example, you can't have `datetime` values `x1`, `y1`, `x2`, and `y2` where `x1 - y1 == timedelta(-1, -5, 0)` `x2 - y2 == timedelta(-2, 85395)`.

Comment: @AvenDesta, RufusVS indeed i can reserve the arguments! thanks a lot